# cycle detection in an undirected graph using dfs and height array

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search

My job is to complete the isCyclic() function in following program. I can handle this job with visited array and passing parent to dfs() function but I am trying another solution, So I use a height array to keep track of distance of nodes in DFS tree for determining parents and cycle. this height array initial by zero. If distance of two node be exactly one these two node are parent child. 
But I cannot understand why my solution doesn't work. can someone tell me why output of this code is not correct?
thanks for your help.

An example of graph and height value of nodes:

```
   /*
    .1
   / \
  .2  .2
     / \
    .3  .3
 */
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Graph
{
    int V;
    list<int> *adj;
public :
    Graph(int V);
    void addEdge(int v,int w);
    bool isCyclic();
};
vector<int> g[100001];
Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
}
void Graph::addEdge(int v,int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w);
    adj[w].push_back(v);
}
int main()
{
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--)
    {
        int _size,N;
        cin>>_size>>N;
        Graph *g = new Graph(_size);
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            int u,v;
            cin>>u>>v;
            g->addEdge(u,v);
        }
        cout<<g->isCyclic()<<endl;
    }
}


/*Please note that it's Function problem i.e.
you need to write your solution in the form of Function(s) only.
Driver Code to call/invoke your function is mentioned above.*/

/*The structure of the class is as follows 
which contains an integer V denoting the no 
of vertices and a list of adjacency vertices.
class Graph
{
    int V;
    list<int> *adj;
public :
    Graph(int V);
    void addEdge(int v,int w);
    bool isCyclic();
};*/
/*You are required to complete this method*/

bool dfs(int v, int hi, list<int> *adj, int *h) {
    h[v] = hi;

    list<int>::iterator it;
    for(it = adj[v].begin(); it != adj[v].end(); it++) {
        int u = *it;

        //cycle detect
        if (h[u]>0 && hi - h[u] > 1)
            return true;

        if (h[u]==0 && dfs(u, hi+1, adj, h))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/*You are required to complete this method*/
bool Graph :: isCyclic()
{
//Your code here
    int h[V];
    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++) h[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i< V; i++) 
        if ( h[i] == 0 && dfs(i, 1, adj, h) ) return true;
    return false;
}
```

A input that make my answer incorrect:

Input:
85 59
0 34 32 54 6 16 45 44 82 52 57 15 20 60 52 44 75 77 48 18 53 75 14 40 39 46 24 26 32 0 39 74 34 29 43 41 45 45 0 42 54 14 58 75 31 67 34 63 16 39 81 69 29 52 67 26 14 6 52 3 48 49 77 83 78 78 81 38 38 38 38 8 53 53 40 84 77 31 63 9 70 16 78 57 69 60 83 83 23 7 43 72 56 35 27 6 70 23 2 24 61 40 74 71 50 29 28 42 60 48 51 2 64 2 59 48 19 57

Its Correct output is:
1

And Your Code's output is:
0

Comment: Have you successfully run you code? What platform/c++ compiler do you use?

Comment: I submit it in here: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/detect-cycle-in-an-undirected-graph/1

Comment: Not sure what you see. When I tried your program in geeksforgeeks, I got `Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)`.

Comment: I see the "Wrong Answer. !!!" message

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Concerning the input, prefer hard-coded code to setup your graph, just to make sure that it is not in the input parsing code that the error is caused. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].